# Is it possible to use glyph Designer with Xcode storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, designer, glyph

I was wondering if you could use Glyph Designer to create a cool font and then use it in an Xcode Storyboard. I know you can use it with cocos2d, but I want to use it in my TableViewCells and navigation bar because I don't like the default font.

If it is not possible is their another program, I can use to make my own custom font?

Answer (score 0):

No. The iOS SDK has no native support for bitmap fonts. You need to have a truetype fonts (ttf) if you want to use custom fonts.